# Read EDI data into database using dynamic template

Tags: c#, sql-server, parsing, text

I have EDI data which I need to read into table. I managed to read the data and it looks good as of now, but I have 2 issues, first is the how to get data into pivot view. Second, reading data that is split across blocks.

EDI is as follows:
000000000000A1000DATA_UP_TO_THIRSTY_FIVE_CHARACTER_NOT_MORE_THAN_SIXTY_THREE000000000000A1000DATA_UP_TO_THIRSTY_FIVE_CHARACTER_NOT_MORE_THAN_SIXTY_THREE000000000000A1000DATA_UP_TO_THIRSTY_FIVE_CHARACTER_NOT_MORE_THAN_SIXTY_THREE----------
Explanation: First 12 is transaction number, next 2 are Field Type, Next 3 are Counter and remaining is the data. Single line length is 250 character, with 80 character for each block (total 3 blocks in each line) and last 10 (dash represent white space) are fillers. As I said I have managed to read the data, the problem is some time counter is in a sequence. That means, 001,002,003, indicating the data split into multiple blocks.
As of now I managed to read split data into table in new row, with previous id as an indicator for relation (split data).
*Table Structure*
ID --- FieldName --- FieldData  --- SplitPrefix
01  --- TransID ---  00000000000 ---- NULL
02 --- FieldType --- A1 --------------- NULL
03 --- Counter ----- 001 -------------- NULL
04 --- ActualData --- *Long text* ----- NULL
05  --- TransID ---  00000000000 ---- NULL
06 --- FieldType --- A1 --------------- NULL
07 --- Counter ----- 002 -------------- NULL
08 --- ActualData --- *Long text* ----- 04

There are about 39 Field type, with different counters. I need to show this data in a pivot view.
P.S: Data is up to 36, but sometimes within 36 there may be different data, like: Date(03152015),Party Code (V1001), etc.

I am looking for some help with TSQL on Sql Server 2008 or Some help with coding.

**More Info:**
I have 3 tables, EdiTemplate: It has template name and description as well as other details related to template
EdiTemplateDetails: It has field related information, field name, type of data, length of data, isDataSplit and etc.
EdiTemplateData: The structure is already provide above, this is where I store the data I read based on "EdiTemplateDetails".

**Even More Info. (sql procedure)**

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(1000),
@blid NVARCHAR(20),
@outsql nvarchar(2000)

SET @blid = '143483328278' -- comment this line in production
SELECT @cols =
STUFF((SELECT N',[' + fieldname + ']'
       FROM TEMPLATEDATA
       WHERE UNIQUEIDENTIFIER LIKE '%'+ @blid +'%'
       FOR XML PATH('')
      ), 1, 1, '');
-- Build dynamic SQL query for pivoting  

SET @outsql =

N' SELECT ' + @cols +
N' FROM (SELECT UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, FIELDNAME, FIELDDATA FROM TemplateData WHERE UNIQUEIDENTIFIER LIKE ''%' + @blid + '%''  ) AS S' +
N' PIVOT ' +
N' (MAX(FIELDDATA) FOR FIELDNAME IN (' + @cols + N')) AS P;';
```

Comment: Let me grab a drink for those characters :)

Comment: I know, lots of text here, don't know what can be the best way to share my issue.

Comment: have you googled SQL PIVOT?

Comment: Yes I did, and even got it working with dynamic columns. It works as long as fields are not ambiguous, i.e. In different transaction, for each field type I have same data, I get error saying "column is used more than once". Btw, I used for xml to create dynamic column list.